# Attempt as assembly on iOS

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

Please note: I'm just trying to learn. Please do not yell at me for toying with assembly.

I have the following method:

```
uint32 test(int16 a, int16 b)
{
  return ( a + b ) & 0xffff;
}
```

I created a .s file based on details I found [here](http://www.shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html).

My .s file contains the following:

```
.macro BEGIN_FUNCTION
.align 2        // Align the function code to a 4-byte (2^n) word boundary.
.arm            // Use ARM instructions instead of Thumb.
.globl _$0      // Make the function globally accessible.
.no_dead_strip _$0  // Stop the optimizer from ignoring this function!
.private_extern _$0
_$0:                // Declare the function.
.endmacro

.macro END_FUNCTION
bx  lr      // Jump back to the caller.
.endmacro


BEGIN_FUNCTION addFunction
  add       r0, r0, r1      // Return the sum of the first 2 function parameters
END_FUNCTION

BEGIN_FUNCTION addAndFunction
  add       r0, r0, r1      // Return the sum of the first 2 function parameters
  ands      r0, r0, r2      // Ands the result of r0 and the third parameter passed
END_FUNCTION
```

So if I call the following:

```
addFunction(10,20)
```

I get what I would expect. But then if I try

```
int addOne = addFunction(0xffff,0xffff); // Result = -2
int addTwo = 0xffff + 0xffff;            // Result = 131070
```

[image: Screenshot of the two values]

My addOne does not end up being the same value as my add two. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the values of addOne and addTwo?

Comment: Also look at the output of objdump to see if your function appears as you expect it.

Comment: +1 "What are the values of addOne and addTwo?", endianness problem?

Comment: I edited the question to include the result values. As far as I can tell, I don't think its an endian problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the `int16_t` parameter `0xffff` to `addFunction` the compiler sign-extends it to fit in the 32-bit register (as it's a signed integer) making it `0xffffffff.` You add two of these together to get `0xfffffffe` and return it. When you do `0xffff + 0xffff` both constants are already 32-bits and so there's no need to sign extend, the result is `0x0001fffe`.

What you need to understand is that when you're using a signed integer and passing the 16-bit value `0xffff` you're actually passing in `-1`, so it's no surprise that `-1 + -1 = -2`. It's also no suprise that `0xffff + 0xffff = 0xfffffffe`.

If you change the (not shown) C declaration of `addFunction` to take two *unsigned* ints, then you'll get the result you desire (the compiler won't do the sign extension).

Comment: This did it exactly and makes perfect sense. You were correct that my c declaration was using signed ints, which I didn't even think about. Changing everything to use uint16 worked like a charm!

Comment: I'd actually recommend you use uint32_t everywhere, and then int32_t only when you need a signed integer. Using 16-bit integers isn't going to provide a performance boost or anything like that, in fact it's likely to make things slower.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's my first time using assembly and I learn best via hands on. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly code assumes a third passed parameter (in R2) but when you call the
function you are only passing 2 parameters. I think the contents of R2 could be anything in your addFunction.

Comment: I think only the addAndFunction expects a third parameter. I'm calling the addFunction which should only expect two as it only uses r0 and r1.

Comment: @Zenox Yes, sorry about that.